# Why won't my java program loop properly?

Tags: java

The following program is supposed to print an options screen where it asks the user to choose an option like S(square), H(shape), T(triangle), or X(shape).

It will print that shape based on the size and character it also asked the user to enter. It's a loop and keeps looping and printing a shape until the user chooses the last option which is Q(quit). Once the user enters Q, it will end.

This program is working the first time and printing a shape. But then when it loops again, it's only printing up to the end of "displayMenu()". and then showing an error saying:

> Enter your option: Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   0

---

Here's the program.. Please help me locate the reason the loop isn't working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Shapes{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      int size = 0;
      char ch = ' ', option = ' ';
      boolean done = false;
      displayWelcome();

      do{
         displayMenu();
         option = getOption(keyboard);
         if(option == 'Q')
            done = true;
         else{
            ch = getCharToPrint(keyboard);
            size = getSize(keyboard);
            if(option == 'S')
               printSquare(size, ch);
            else if(option == 'H')
               printHShape(size, ch);
            else if(option == 'T')
               printTriangle(size, ch);
            else
               printXShape(size, ch);

               System.out.println();
         }
      } while(!done);

      System.out.print("Done");
   }

   public static void displayWelcome(){
      System.out.println("WELCOME TO THE SHAPE PRINTER!");
      System.out.println("-----------------------------");
   }

   public static void displayMenu(){
      System.out.println("  Options:  ");
      System.out.println("    S)quare  ");
      System.out.println("    H) Shape  ");
      System.out.println("    T)riangle  ");
      System.out.println("    X) Shape  ");
      System.out.println("    Q)uit  ");
      System.out.println("-------------------------------");

   }

   public static char getOption(Scanner keyboard){
      char answer;
      String input;
      do{
         System.out.print("Enter your option: ");
         input = keyboard.nextLine();
         answer = input.charAt(0);
   } while (answer != 'S' && answer != 'H' && answer != 'T' && answer != 'X' && answer != 'Q');
   return answer;
   }

   public static char getCharToPrint(Scanner keyboard){
      char ch;
      String input;
      System.out.print("Enter a character: ");
      input = keyboard.nextLine();
      ch = input.charAt(0);
      return ch;
   }

   public static int getSize(Scanner keyboard){
      int size;
      do{
         System.out.print("Enter an odd, positive number: ");
         size = keyboard.nextInt();
      } while(size % 2 == 0 || size < 1);
      return size;   
   }

   public static void printSquare(int n, char ch){
      int row, col;
      for(row = 0; row < n; row++){
         for (col = 0; col < n; col++){
            if(row == 0 || row == n-1 || col == 0 || col == n-1)
               System.out.print(ch);
            else 
               System.out.print(' '); 
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

   public static void printHShape(int n, char ch){
      int row, col, mid = n/2;
      for(row = 0; row < n; row++){
         for(col = 0; col < n; col++){
            if(col == 0 || col == n - 1 || row == mid)
               System.out.print(ch);
            else
               System.out.print(' ');
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

   public static void printTriangle(int n, char ch){
      int row, col;
      for(row = 0; row < n; row++){
         for (col = 0; col < n; col++){
            if(col == 0 || row == n - 1 || row == col)
               System.out.print(ch);
            else
               System.out.print(' ');
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

   public static void printXShape(int n, char ch){
      int row, col, mid = n/2;
      for(row = 0; row < n; row++){
         for (col = 0; col < n; col++){
            if(row == col || row + col == n - 1)
               System.out.print(ch);
            else
               System.out.print(' ');
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to use things like `input.charAt(0)` without making sure the string isn't empty.  Even after you fix the problem by adding `nextLine()`, you will still get an exception if the user hits ENTER on a blank line, and that's not good.  In `getOption`, you could say `answer = (input.empty()) ? '*' : input.getChar(0);` since `*` isn't a legal option.  I'll let you figure out how to fix `getCharToPrint`.

Answer (score 4):

**problem:**

```
size = keyboard.nextInt();
```

You are getting the input from user which will have a new line character which by then consume by `nextLine()` on the second loop thus throwing `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this line `answer = input.charAt(0);`.

**solution:**

consume the newline character first before looping to the options

```
System.out.print("Enter an odd, positive number: ");
     size = keyboard.nextInt();
     keyboard.nextLine();
```

Comment: I'll buy that for dollar

Comment: @MadProgrammer sold!! :))

Comment: @ScaryWombat :)) ahahaha